# Regex search for multiple tokens in string

Tags: python, regex, loops

so im supposed to get a string and be able to separate it into many tokens in order.
so if my string is 25 + 90 - x * z30 my output should be
Line: 25 + 90 - x * z30

Number: 25

Punctuation: +

Number: 90

Punctuation: -

Identifier: x

Punctuation: *

Identifier: z30

currently my code is at the very early stages

```
txt = '25 + 90 - x * z30'

number = '[0-9]+'
identifier = '[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'
punctuation = '[(/*+)-]'

        id = re.search(identifier, txt)
        num = re.search(number, txt)
        punc = re.search(punctuation, txt)
        print('Line: ', txt)
        print('Identifier: ', id)
        print('Number: ', num)
        print('punctuation', punc)
```

I am confused as to how to keep  reading the string after the first search to get the next search for each category and on how to have them appear in order. do I have to do a specific loop to get it like that?
because currently I only get the first search for each one and in the order its hard coded in

Comment: so condensing number, identifier and punctuation  all into one variable would be better?

Comment: you can use `re.split('(\d+)|([\+\-\*\\])|([a-z]\d+)|([a-zA-Z])', txt)` then check each elemnt and print it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to split the string into tokens (`txt.split()` will do) and then check each token to see what regex it matches. Something like this (untested).

```
print("Line:", txt)
for token in txt.split():
    id = re.search(identifier, token)
    num = re.search(number, txt)
    punc = re.search(punctuation, txt)
    if id and id.group(0) == token:   # there was a match, and the match was the whole token
        print("Identifier:", token)
    elif num and num.group(0) == token:
        print("Number:", token)
    elif punc and punc.group(0) == token:
        print("Punctuation:", token)
    else:
        print("Unrecognized:", token)
```

There are better ways to do this. For example, you could put your regexes into a dictionary and iterate over that instead of writing a chain of `if`s.

Comment: This definitely helped a lot and gave me an idea on how to keep this going